# java random values that not repeat

Tags: java, random, duplicates

I need to pick few random values from `ArrayList`, but values cannot duplicate. With code below i simply pick random values but they can duplicate.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        index = random.nextInt(menuItems.size());
        HashMap<String, String> urls = new HashMap<String, String>();

        urls.put("Value", menuItems.get(index).get(KEY_URL));

        randomitems.add(urls);

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps, look up "shuffle".

Comment: You realize I trust that 'random' and 'not repeat' are mutually contradictory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't need to keep `menutItems` in a specific order, you can simply shuffle it and take the first 5 items:

```
Collections.shuffle(menuItems);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> urls = new HashMap<String, String>();
    urls.put("Value", menuItems.get(i).get(KEY_URL));
    randomitems.add(urls);
}
```

If you do need to keep `menuItems` as it is, you can make a copy first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is in the nature of randomness that the same number may be given again.

To get rid of that you have to manually check the new random number against previously recieved ones and throw all that you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate your list, so you dont mess up your old list

```
List<Object> randomList = new ArrayList<Object>(oldList);
```

pick one

```
int index = new Random().nextInt(randomList.size());
Object randomObj = randomList.get(index);
randomList.remove(index);
```

so every time you pick one, you cannot pick that one again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the title of your question here.  I use a `Set` to make sure every number is unique and I don't stop adding numbers until it equals the size I want.  Then I convert it to a `List`:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sandbox {

    private static final int TOTAL_NUMBERS_I_WANT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Set<Integer> nonRepeatingRandomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        while (nonRepeatingRandomNumbers.size() < TOTAL_NUMBERS_I_WANT) {
            nonRepeatingRandomNumbers.add(random.nextInt());
        }
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(nonRepeatingRandomNumbers);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```