# How to get the random values from List in java>

Tags: java, random-access

Here my code is,

```
List<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>();
```

from above list i am getting values like below:

```
for (HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> entry : al) {

            for (Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> mapEntry : entry
                    .entrySet()) {
                key = mapEntry.getKey();
                value = mapEntry.getValue();
            }

        }
```

I am getting values without any problem,Here my problem is i need to get values randomly(not duplicate values).How i can get the values randomly.Please can any one help me.

Thanking in  Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929554/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-value-of-a-hashmap-randomly-in-java/929769#929769

Comment: Do you want random values from `HashMap`, or you also want those `HashMap`s to be chosen at random?

Comment: i need random values from hashmap.

Answer (score 4):

[Shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the list then iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("abc", 1);
map.put("def", 2);
map.put("ghi", 3);

//Creating a list
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());

//Generating a random value
int index = new Random().nextInt(list.size());

//Result
Integer value = list.get(index);
```

Comment: It is worked but duplicates are repeated

Comment: @user2681425 try this link with no repeats http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258063/java-random-values-that-not-repeat

Comment: @user2681425 it will help to you

Answer (score 1):

Simple util generic method :

```
static public <T> T getRandom(List<T> list){
    if(list == null || list.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }else{
        return list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers that just contain code blocks aren't always as self explanatory as they may seem to the people who wrote them. Can you explain how your code answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use shuffle() in collections class.It will satisfy your need.

List list=new ArrayList();
Collections.shuffle(list);

Comment: List<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>();     Collections.shuffle(al);

Comment: but i am not getting random values

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ThreadLocalRandom**. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html for further details.

Similar to what Siddh has suggested.